# Why upwork authentication api always response failed?

Tags: upwork-api

I am building an application with Upwork api.

Now I do the first thing to get a grant code to exchange access token.

The api documentation says:

======

Endpoint
GET
/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize
‍
Parameters:

1. response_type

required, string
‍
The corresponding grant type. Use code for Authorization Code Grant.

2. client_id

required, string
‍
Your Client ID.

3. redirect_uri

required, string

‍Redirect URI, must be equal or similar to the callback specified in the key settings.

======

I use this url to get the code but always response failed

[https://api.upwork.com/graphql/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[ClientID]&redirect_uri=[Encoded](https://api.upwork.com/graphql/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%5BClientID%5D&redirect_uri=%5BEncoded) Callback URL]

the response is:

{
"1": {
"str": "Authentication failed"
}
}

I tried using the redirect URL with encoding and without encoding, still get failed.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.